# Handling session resources in MY_Controller with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've added a function that checks if the user is trying to use/access something which requires a session. I'd love to hear some criticisms of my choice of design.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
                $this->load->view('header_public_view');
                if($this->login_required())
                  //do something, redirect etc..
            }
            else {
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $data['user'] = $this->user_model->get_user($this->session->userdata('userid'));
                $this->load->view('header_user_view', $data);
            }
        }

    }

    function login_required() {
        if($this->uri->total_segments() > 3)
            $request = $this->uri->segment(3);
        else
            $request = $this->uri->segment(2);
        foreach(unserialize(SESSION_RESOURCES) as $required) {
            if($request == $required)
                return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to check for `is_logged_in`.  If you destroy/build the session data correctly all you should care about is "*Does a user id exist in the session?*", then you can let your main controller handle the rest.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    //here we just build some constants to check against values
    //in the permissions array
    const PERM_READ = "read";
    const PERM_EDIT = "update";
    const PERM_DELETE = "delete";

    //here we let the main controller take care of our auth/permissions/roles etc
    //first check if a user id exists in the session
    //if so assign a user, group, permissions and check for authentication where
    //you need it ( ie: child controllers)

    protected $_user, $_group, $_permissions = array();

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        //check for a user id in the session
        $this->user = ( $this->session->userdata('uid') )
                    ? User::find_by_id( $this->session->userdata('uid') )
                    : NULL;

        //if user exists assign permissions and group
          if ($this->user !== NULL) {
              $this->_assign_group();
              $this->_assign_permissions();
              $this->_check_for_banned_users();
          }

    }

    protected function _assign_group() {
        return $this->group = $this->user->group->name;
    }


    // {["read", "update", "delete"]}
    protected function _assign_permissions() {
        return  $this->permissions = json_decode($this->user->permissions);
    }

    protected function _check_for_banned_users() {
        if ($this->group === 'banned') {
            show_error('You have been banned from this website!');
            return;
        }
    }

    protected function _can_read(){
        return (bool) ( in_array( self::PERM_READ, $this->permissions) );
    }

    public function _can_edit(){
        return (bool) ( in_array( self::PERM_EDIT, $this->permissions) );
    }

    public function _can_delete(){
        return (bool) ( in_array( self::PERM_DELETE, $this->permissions) );
    }
}
```

This might give you some idea, as your user table won't look like that, I'm sure.

Now, you have control over any child classes.

```
class some_child extends MY_Controller{

     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
     }
     public function show_something(){

          if($this->is_ajax_request()){
              if($this->user && $this->_can_read()){
              //yes a user exists and is logged in,
              //yes he has permission to read from this section
              $this->load->view('some_view');
              }
          }
          else
             show_404();
     }
}
```

Just be careful to destroy your session properly.

```
function logout(){
    $this->session->set_userdata(array(
         'uid'  => 0,
         //any others you created upon user login
    ));
    return (bool) $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```